# Knowledge article created in test class not returning in SOSL

Tags: apex, community, code-coverage

I have a class which is used in Chat bot to return the article links to the customer according to the product he selects.

This is the class that I have created :

```
public class FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot 
{
   public static List<Search.SearchResult> articlelist=new List<Search.SearchResult>();
    /** Inputs */
   public class FAQSearchInput{
       @InvocableVariable(required=true)
       public String sKeyword;
   }

   /** Outputs */
   public class FAQSearchOutput{
       @InvocableVariable(required=true)
       public String sFAQSearchResult;
   }

   /** Invocable Method */
   @InvocableMethod(label='Search FAQ')
   public static List<FAQSearchOutput> searchFAQ(List<FAQSearchInput> faqSearchInput)
   {
       String sArticleBaseUrl = getCommunityArticleBaseUrl();
       String sKeyword = faqSearchInput[0].sKeyword;
    System.debug('sKeyword '+sKeyword);
       // Build the SOSL query

       String sQuery = 'FIND \'' + sKeyword + 
         '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion(Id, Title, UrlName WHERE PublishStatus = \'Online\' AND Language = \'en_US\' AND IsVisibleInPkb = true)WITH SNIPPET (target_length=255) LIMIT 3';

       //System.debug('sQuery----- '+);
       // Perform the SOSL search
       Search.SearchResults searchResults = Search.find(sQuery);

       // Use search results to get the list of articles
       articlelist = searchResults.get('KnowledgeArticleVersion');

       String sFAQSearchResult = '';

       // Loop through all the articles to get article info
       for (Search.SearchResult searchResult : articlelist)
       {
           KnowledgeArticleVersion article = (KnowledgeArticleVersion) searchResult.getSObject();
           String sArticleSummary = summarizeArticleForBot(sArticleBaseUrl, article);
           sFAQSearchResult = sFAQSearchResult + sArticleSummary;
       }

       if (sFAQSearchResult == '') sFAQSearchResult = 'No results found.';

       // Build the output structure containing the results
       List<FAQSearchOutput> faqSearchOutputs = new List<FAQSearchOutput>();
       FAQSearchOutput faqSearchOutput = new FAQSearchOutput();
       faqSearchOutput.sFAQSearchResult = sFAQSearchResult;
       faqSearchOutputs.add(faqSearchOutput);
       system.debug(faqSearchOutput);
       return faqSearchOutputs;   
   }     

   /** Helper method that summarizes the article */
   public static String summarizeArticleForBot(String sArticleBaseUrl,
                                               KnowledgeArticleVersion article)
   {
       String sSummary, sURL;
       sURL = sArticleBaseUrl + article.UrlName;

       sSummary = 'Article: ' + article.Title + '\n'+
                  'URL: ' + sURL + '\n\n';

       return sSummary;
   }

   /** Helper method to get the base URL for the community */
   public static string getCommunityArticleBaseUrl()
   {
       // Gets the network for your community
       // TO DO: Replace 'MY_COMMUNITY_NAME' with the name of your community!
       List<Network> communityNetworks =
           [SELECT Id FROM Network WHERE Name ='EFI Communities'];

       String sArticleBaseUrl = '';
       if (communityNetworks.size()>0)
       {
           Network communityNetwork = communityNetworks[0];
           String sLoginUrl = Network.getLoginUrl(communityNetwork.id);
           sArticleBaseUrl = sLoginUrl.replace('/login', '/article/');

           // Write to the debug log in case we want to debug how we parse out the URL...
           System.debug('MyDebug - Community Login URL: ' + sLoginUrl);
           System.debug('MyDebug - Article Base URL: ' + sArticleBaseUrl);
       }
       return sArticleBaseUrl;
   }
}
```

Test class created for above class is :

```
@isTest
public class TestFetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot 
{
   @isTest
   public static void checkProductArticles()
   {
       test.startTest();
       FAQ__kav akv=new FAQ__kav();
       List<FAQ__kav> kvlist=new List<FAQ__kav>();
       akv.UrlName='Digital';
       akv.Title='Digital StoreFront & VDP';
       kvlist.add(akv);
       insert kvlist;
       test.stopTest();
       System.debug('kvlist[0].id '+kvlist[0].id);
       List<Knowledgearticleversion> obj1 = [SELECT Id,Title,PublishStatus,Language,IsVisibleInPkb,KnowledgeArticleId FROM Knowledgearticleversion WHERE id =: kvlist[0].id];
       //List<FAQ__kav> ka=[Select id,title from FAQ__kav];
       System.debug('obj1.KnowledgeArticleId'+obj1[0].KnowledgeArticleId);
       KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(obj1[0].KnowledgeArticleId, true);
       System.debug('FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.articlelist '+FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.articlelist.size());
       System.debug('---- '+obj1[0].PublishStatus);
       System.debug('---- '+obj1[0].Language);
       System.debug('---- '+obj1[0].IsVisibleInPkb);
       List<FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.FAQSearchInput> searchList=new List<FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.FAQSearchInput>();
       List<FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.FAQSearchOutput> searchOtputList=new List<FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.FAQSearchOutput>();
       FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.FAQSearchInput searchKeyword=new FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.FAQSearchInput();
       searchKeyword.sKeyword='Digital StoreFront & VDP';
       searchList.add(searchKeyword);
       searchOtputList=FetchKnowledgeArticlesChatbot.searchFAQ(searchList);
       System.assertEquals(1,searchOtputList.size());
   }
}
```

When I run the test class the code coverage is 70%.It is not going into the for loop even if I have created the knowledge article in test class.

Even if I remove the all conditions from SOSL in class still it is returning 0 records in it while running test class.

Please suggest me the solution for this.Thanks in advance

Comment: What do the System.debug statements show in the test class?

Comment: It is showing draft for publishstatus,IsinvisibleInpkb is false..Now you will say there are conditions on SOSL but I removed all the conditions on the sosl and tried it is still not giving me any record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer for this.

You need to place searched object id into Test.setFixedSearchResults in test class after creating record.

```
Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
fixedSearchResults[0] = objKav.Id;
Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue.

Make sure you write the code within the test method its being referenced not within a test setup method, similar to a mock response.

Here's documentation for reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm